# FusionAuth support for signed and encrypted assertions

Tags: encryption, assertion, signed, fusionauth

As a SP, does FusionAuth support signed and encrypted assertions? and if so, does it require any configuration?

Comment: Are you specifically asking if FusionAuth can encrypt SAML v2 assertions when acting as the Identity Provider, or if FusionAuth can accept encrypted assertions when acting as the Service Provider?

Comment: @robotdan if FusionAuth can accept encrypted assertions when acting as the Service Provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 10/23/23 and FusionAuth release 1.47.1, it appears from https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/2378 that FusionAuth does not support encrypted assertions as SP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FusionAuth does support signed and encrypted assertions. As of version 1.47, FusionAuth is compatible with a SAML v2 Service Provider (SP) that requires encrypted assertions. This functionality is only available when FusionAuth is acting as the SAMLv2 Identity Provider (IdP). You can enable and configure the behavior on the “SAML” tab of a given Application.

However, it's important to note that FusionAuth doesn't support "Service Provider Public Certificates" for assertion encryption at this time.

For more information, please see the FusionAuth [Documentation](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/core-concepts/applications#assertion-encryption).

Comment: Mark, thanks for the response. My question is for when FusionAuth is used as a SP. and, if an Idp returns a SAML response with encrypted and signed assertions, will FusionAuth be able to handle them? and, is there any configuration that should be done to support it or does it come out of the box?